# Yum: Can a package have a alias or short name?

Tags: linux, bash, yum

I have installed yum package "mysql" previously using :

```
yum install mysql
```

However when I try and list installed packages using filter:

```
yum list install *mysql"
```

It shows nothing but when I list installed packages without I can see package names which I believe is what my mysql installed:

```
mariadb.x86_64                                                                            1:5.5.65-1.el7                                                        @gl
mariadb-libs.x86_64                                                                       1:5.5.65-1.el7
```

Does yum have a concept of short names or aliases? just trying to understand how mysql maps to mariadb.exe and have googled various resources but didn't find anything obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RPM packages can declare `Provides:` which mean that they provide some named capability. These are treated as equivalent to package names when yum decides what packages to install.

A recent version of the `mariadb` package does indeed declare several provides:

```
$ rpm -q --provides mariadb
config(mariadb) = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
mariadb = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
mariadb(x86-64) = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
mysql = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
mysql(x86-64) = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
mysql-compat-client = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
mysql-compat-client(x86-64) = 3:10.4.13-2.fc32
```

Packages can also declare `Obsoletes:` which are packages that the current package replaces. (Though this package doesn't declare any.) If a package with the old name is already installed, running `yum upgrade` will replace the old package with the new one.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain that, really helps my understanding.

Comment: Note - The package must already be installed for `rpm -q --provides mariadb` to work.